# How to get content of <div> with HtmlAgilityPack - C#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have html source:

```
<div class="lit-plot">
    <b class="red">خلاصه داستان :</b>
Content
</div>
```

I want to get the value of `<div>` (not `<b>` and only the string "Content") with HtmlAgilityPack. What is the best way to do this?

Here is what am I doing.  `movieDesHTMLSource` is given html source.  I don't know how to access the `InnerHtml`!

```
string movieDes;

//Exctact the movie's description HTML source
var movieDesHTMLSource = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
movieDesHTMLSource.LoadHtml(postPageHTMLDes[95].InnerHtml);   
var src = movieDesHTMLSource.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'lit-plot')]");
```

Comment: Where are you running into trouble?  This is a fairly basic question that should be answered by the documentation and tutorials.  Can you share what you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Xpath `text()` to retrieve just the text inside div tag.

```
var html = @"<body>
           <div class='lit-plot'>
                <b class='red'>خلاصه داستان :</b>
            Content
        </div>
        </body>";

var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
var htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'lit-plot')]/text()");
foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlNodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText.Trim());
}
```

Fiddle here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/mXFs8k

I recommend that you wrap your content inside `<p>` or `<span>` etc tags then you can easily target it using HtmlAgilityPack.